# Why using UIImageOrientationDownMirrored/UIImageOrientationUpMirrored not working for flipping

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios10

What i am doing is, flipping the image using UIImageOrientationDownMirrored/UIImageOrientationUpMirrored. Once Flipped(which happens) I have stored the info about the flip I have applied on a particular image so that I may retrieve the original orientation of the image before it was flipped, so that I may flip it again and the new flip applies to the original image, so I reverse flip it and apply new flip. But this doesn't seem to work, the image doesn't flip as it was required to. As if reverse flip didn't happen. can anyone tell me why?

**I just wanted to ask one thing, does this UIImageOrientationDownMirrored show effect on an image only when it's in a UIImageView or does it actually invert your UIImage?**

Comment: Share your code. so, it will easy to understand & solve the issue.

Comment: I just wanted to ask one thing, does this UIImageOrientationDownMirrored show effect on an image only when it's in a UIImageView or does it actually invert your UIImage?

Comment: If you will take picture using camera and get it, only then that image is rotating ...this is by apple only "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageorientation/uiimageorientationdownmirrored" check this link..You will get the code to rotate image in original direction